# Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse does not work for JDK 1.7

Tags: eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I need to install OEPE into Eclipse STS (luna) using JDK 1.7.  I did this 2 months ago without a problem but had to recently reinstall.  I get the error, 'Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse requires Java 8 or higher'.  I need to find the older version of OEPE that works with JDK 1.7.

I saw that the current OEPE installs 'Oracle WebLogic Scripting Tools' and 'Oracle WebLogic Server Tools' with version 7.3.4.  I remember that when I previously (successfully) installed OEPE into STS, the versions for these were 7.3.3.  I googled and found Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.1.3.4 and installed it from there.  I saw that the versions of the above 2 items are now 7.3.3 but ... I still receive the same error.

Note:
- STS: Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE  Build Id: 201503100339   Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)
- My weblogic install is weblogic 12c

Any help?
Thanks,
Bill

Comment: If there's a vote down, you need to provide information on why.  It helps no one if  you don't provide the reasons.  This is a community of support, and we need to work to make sure it can be the best it can (by especially avoiding the common dynamics seen in other sites that have come and go).

Comment: i'm in the same boat.. did you figure out the eclipse update site?